# Handle iOS Push Notification when app in backgroud

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, appdelegate

I have to handle push when the app in background / running. I'm using firebase and native push services. Setting up **Capability** - **Background Fetch**. I'm receiving push's all and I can open app taping on push view when the app in the background and handle push when the app is running. But I have to implement follow:

*When app running.*

Receive push, show alert, logout user. **Works!**

*When app in background / closed. Open app from the push.*

Handling this action in **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method. **Works!**

*When app in background / closed. When open app from the app icon.*

Handling this action in **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method. **Doesn't work!**.

How can I get push *When app in background / closed*. Save data (ex. badge count or push can in AppDelegate variable). And get this in **applicationDidBecomeActive** method?

Comment: Hope this helps.. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app?language=objc. It worked for me when app was in background.

Comment: @AnilArigela; that helps. Please add your comment in answer.

Comment: One issue fixed! _To send a background notification, create a remote notification with an aps dictionary that includes only the content-available key_ MUST BE IN YOUR PAYLOAD. Now I have another issue when app closed / terminated this is not works.

Answer (score 0):

to handle push notifications you need to implement two methods, one is called when the app is closed, and one is called when app is in foreground.

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
   /// Called when the app receive the notification in foreground
   /// - Parameter center: <#center description#>
   /// - Parameter notification: <#notification description#>
   /// - Parameter completionHandler: <#completionHandler description#>
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
       let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

       // Get aps object
       let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! [String : Any]
       // Do your stuff here

       // This line is NEEDED, otherwise push will not be fired
       completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound]) // Display notification depending on your needed
   }


   /// Detect when user tap on a push message when app is closed
   /// - Parameter center: <#center description#>
   /// - Parameter response: <#response description#>
   /// - Parameter completionHandler: <#completionHandler description#>
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

       let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
       // Get aps object
       let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! [String : Any]
       // Do your stuff here

       // This line is NEEDED, otherwise push will not be fired
       completionHandler()
   }
}
```

And in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` set your AppDelegate as delegate:

```
// Set AppDelegate as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

Hope this can help
:-)

Comment: _Detect when user tap on a push message when app is closed_. But I need to **save data from push** when app is closed and get data on **tap on app icon when app is closed**.

Comment: You can't save data when push is notified because is managed by OS. The only way to do it, is to save data, and then get it when user tap the push notification. Of course, if user doesn't tap the push you could lost data. Try to implement a method to launch every time user start your app to ask data to a server